# simple xpath query not working

Tags: php, html, curl, xpath, domdocument

This snippet of code is not working:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in test.php on line 13
```

but the xpath query seems obviously correct... and the url provided obviously have a tag .
I tried to replace the query even with '//html' but no luck.
I always use xpath and this is a strange behaviour.

```
<?php
$_url = 'http://www.portaleaste.com/it/Aste/Detail/876989';

$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $_url);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result2 = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);

$doc2 = new DOMDocument();
@$doc2->load($result2);
$xpath2 = new DOMXpath($doc2);
$txt = $xpath2->query('//p[@id="descrizione"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $txt;
?>
```

Comment: It would be useful if you identified which line was line 13!!!!

Comment: Are you certain you don't need to specify the namespace?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think we can infer that it is the line with the XPath expression on it!

Comment: @JKesMc9tqIQe9M And we almost all know that _Assumption is the mother of all mistakes_ to keep it polite. Its the responsibility of the questioner to make things as clear as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your xpath query as it is correct syntax and the node does exist. The problematic line is this:

```
@$doc2->load($result2);
// DOMDocument::load — Load XML from a file
```

You are not loading the result page that you got from your curl request properly. To load the response,

Use this instead:

```
@$doc2->loadHTML($result2);
// DOMDocument::loadHTML — Load HTML from a string
```

[Here's a sample output you'd expect](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IFsGUe)

Comment: @MarcoMarsala yes very subtle but important. glad this helped